# Am now receiving Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED] error

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-manifest, android-logcat

I have searched through the questions looking for an answer to my problem. I have tried, renaming, doing a clean build, invalidate caches / restart, and am running out of ideas. Any suggestions would be appreciated. The only plugin I'm using is the "Android Property Initializer". Below is a copy of my manifest and the logcat:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.brainbox.localledge.app">
  <application
    android:name=".ParseApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <activity
      android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
      android:parentActivityName="Activities.LoginActivity"
      android:name="Activities.SignUpActivity"
      android:label="@string/title_activity_sign_up">
    </activity>
    <activity
      android:name="Activities.LoginActivity"
      android:label="@string/title_activity_login">
    </activity>
    <activity
      android:parentActivityName="Activities.LoginActivity"
      android:name="Activities.ResetPasswordActivity"
      android:label="@string/title_activity_reset_password">
    </activity>
  </application>

</manifest>
```

here is the logcat:

```
05-07 09:01:22.522    1771-1771/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
05-07 09:01:22.522    1771-1771/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ CheckJNI is OFF
05-07 09:01:22.538    1771-1771/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
05-07 09:01:22.538    1771-1771/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
05-07 09:01:22.546    1771-1771/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
05-07 09:01:22.546    1771-1771/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
05-07 09:01:22.646    1771-1771/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
05-07 09:01:22.678    1616-1616/com.brainbox.dropnotelitealpha.app E/EGL_genymotion﹕ egl: current context mark for deletion
05-07 09:01:22.694      479-500/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/com.brainbox.localledge.app
05-07 09:01:22.698      479-500/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/com.brainbox.localledge.app
05-07 09:01:22.698      479-500/system_process I/PackageManager﹕ Copying native libraries to /data/app-lib/vmdl-1380044634
05-07 09:01:22.710      479-500/system_process W/PackageParser﹕ /data/app/vmdl-1380044634.tmp (at Binary XML file line #11): <activity> does not have valid android:name
05-07 09:01:22.746      479-500/system_process D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 397K, 41% free 11120K/18828K, paused 11ms+2ms, total 33ms
05-07 09:01:22.750    1771-1771/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
05-07 09:01:22.754    1771-1777/? D/jdwp﹕ Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
05-07 09:01:22.754    1771-1777/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
05-07 09:01:22.758    1771-1778/? E/cutils-trace﹕ Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

As you can see, line #11 is a valid name. I have also tried using the full path to the name and the results are the same. Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Package names should start with a lowercase ASCII letter a-z.

Names such as `Activities.SignUpActivity` do not follow this pattern. Also, if you intended to scope it in your package, make the name start with dot `.`.

Specifically, this error is a result of [`buildClassName()`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageParser.java#1480) returning `null`, trying to figure out a class name from your package name and activity name.

Comment: Thank you. I'm feeling pretty edumacated right about now. It didn't even cross my mind to check the package.